# How to copy the message of the previous commit into the new commit to edit it

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, todo

I write my commits in the following way, namely I try to document what has been done and what remains to be done (todo list):

```
Done: 
- task1 done
Todo: 
- task2
-- implement feature1
-- implement feature2
- task3
-- implement feature1
-- implement feature1
```

Is there a way to automatically copy the content of the previous commit into the new commit to edit (in my case, could be interesting for the todo list)

If someone have another system of "todo list" integrated with git, I am also happy to hear

Comment: Why not just keep a text file with the todo list? Bit weird to have it as part of the commit message

Comment: Some IDEs do this automatically or at least provide an easy way to see and reuse previous commit messages. (I'm thinking of IntelliJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically copy the content of the previous commit into the new commit to edit (in my case, could be interesting for the todo list)

Sure. Look at the `-C` and `-c` arguments to `git commit`:

> `-C <commit>, --reuse-message=<commit>`
>
> Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit.
>
> `-c <commit>, --reedit-message=<commit>`
>
> Like -C, but with -c the editor is invoked, so that the user can further edit the commit message.

If you want to make a new commit that re-uses the messages from the current HEAD commit, just run:

```
git commit -c HEAD
```

Or if you want to minimize typing:

```
git commit -c@
```

(Because `@` is another name for `HEAD`.)